# Calculate the rate of emission

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A source usually emits particles at a rate of 60 per minute. But how many particles would 
be emitted in one hour if (a) the usual rate of emission was increased by a factor of 60? 
(b) the usual rate of emission was increased by 25%? (c) the usual rate of emission was 
decreased by 75%? (d) the rate of emission was increased to 200% of its usual value? (e) the 
usual rate of emission was decreased by 100%?

Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this sort of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $60$ particles are emitted every minute and there are $60$ minutes in one hour, there are $60\cdot60=3600$ particles emitted in one hour.

(a) If the usual rate of emission was increased by a factor of $60$, then there would be $60\cdot60=3600$ particles emitted every minute. Thus $3600\cdot60=216,000$ particles emitted in one hour.

(b) If it is increased by $25$% we will have $75$ particles emitted every minute. This is so because $25$% of $60$ is $15$. Thus $75\cdot60=4500$ particles emitted in one hour.

(c) If it is decreased by $75%$, then we have only $15$ particles emitted every minute. Thus $15\cdot60=900$ particles emitted in one hour.

(d) If it is increased by 200% we will have 180 particles emitted every minute. Thus 180*60=10800 particles emitted every hour.

(e) If the usual amount was decreased by 100%, then there would be zero particles emitted.

Comment: For (a), doesn't factor mean multiplication? I suspect 60 increased by a factor of 60 would be 3600, not 120.

Comment: You are correct. I overlooked that. I read it as increased by 60, that is incorrect. Thank you. I'll edit that.

Comment: Thank you. Can Sigma Σ be used as a method to answer this question?

Comment: You're welcome! :) I'm not sure if summations could be used. That is a good question.